# Cannot reference plugin classes grails 2.4.4

Tags: plugins, groovy, dependency-management

I have added the following entry to BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile ":rest-client-builder:2.1.1"
```

The plugin supposedly installed correctly and the project compiled.

I am trying to import the RestBuilder class in a controller but the class name cannot be resolved?

```
import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder

Groovy:unable to resolve class grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder
```

I have no spent an hour and a half trying to figure out why this is not working.  I am not sure what else to do or what information to provide as to get this working.  Can anyone well versed in groovy explain how this could be or offer some advice??

Thank you

Comment: try grails clean-all command followed by grails compile. See whether your plugin classes are present under /terget directory?

Comment: I can't tell if closing and re-opening ggts or the above suggestion work but either way.  Thank you. :)

Comment: `grails clean-all` followed by `grails compile` fixed my problem

Comment: I had the same issue with my GGTS 3.6.4 and Grails 2.3.11. Additionally to `grails clean-all` and `grails compile` I had to close and reopen the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `grails clean-all` and `grails compile` from **grails console**(Windows command prompt).

Using the same in intellij(v15.0) run target did not work for me.